# Use of hyphen as conjunction

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, hyphenation

I came across this sentence in my GRE preparation

> The Bible is fertile ground for exegesis--over the past five centuries there have been as many interpretations as there are pages in the Old Testament.

The document I am reading has several more such sentences in which `--` is used as a conjunction. It seems like semicolon `;` would have been more appropriate. Moreover, I do not remember ever seeing such use of double-hyphen. Is this an accepted usage of the hyphen?

Comment: It isn't a hyphen, it's an [em-dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) (_Em_ being a printer's term for the amount of space it takes up.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a false assumption. The "double-hyphen" in the sentence does not represent a hyphen, but is a typographical method of representing an em dash when that symbol is otherwise unavailable. It doesn't signal a conjunction at all.